# MySQL - Duplicate Entry for Key

Tags: mysql

I'm getting an error when trying to add an entry to a table called `collectionStatus`

```
Duplicate entry '565_xxxxxx_gmail_com-toUpload' for key 'hotFolderPathAndParent'
```

I went back the table and deleted the row that contained the field '565_xxxxxx_gmail_com' and tried to re run the add and I still get the error.

I've never really worked with indexes so I'm not sure how to get around this.  I'd like to clear out everything having to do with 565_xxxxxx_gmail_com so I can reprocess from my side.

```
  `collectionStatus` (
  `rowID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fileCount2process` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `hotFolderPath` varchar(260) NOT NULL,
  `parentFolderOf_hotFolderPath` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `collectionCreated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `URL` char(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `UUID` char(37) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  UNIQUE KEY `rowID_UNIQUE` (`rowID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hotFolderPathAndParent` (`hotFolderPath`,`parentFolderOf_hotFolderPath`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Bucket for collections pending and created.'
```

*edit to add table details

Comment: Could you give us the full mysql table info?Are you certain that the key is deleted? (in some mysql ui systems you have to explicitly confirm the deletion).

Comment: No I'm not sure. I know for sure that '565_xxxxxx_gmail_com' does not show up when I do a `select hotFolderPath from collectionStatus where hotFolderPath = '565_xxxxxx_gmail_com'`

Comment: `'565_xxxxxx_gmail_com'` != `'565_xxxxxx_gmail_com-toUpload'`, so your `where =` won't show you that row.

Comment: Use `select hotFolderPath from collectionStatus where hotFolderPath like '565_xxxxxx_gmail_com%'` instead, to check for all strings starting with `565_xxxxxx_gmail_com`

Comment: Also, what exact statement are you using for inserting in `collectionStatus`?

Answer (score 1):

The column `parentFolderOf_hotFolderPath` can only have 8 characters. When you add the value `565_xxxxxx_gmail_com-toUpload` it will add the value with  the first 8 characters: `565_xxxx`. You probably have the value `565_xxxx` in your database?